# reactNative Expo: AxiosError: Network Error

Tags: react-native, axios, expo

There is same code for 3 urls, but I have error in 2nd and 3rd, I can not find more information about this error, I try fetch static jSon file but nothing changed.
I changed Axois with Fetch and I get new error "TypeError: Failed to fetch".

```js
axios
  .get("https://dummyjson.com/products", {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": true,
      "Access-Control-Request-Headers": "Content-Type, x-requested-with",
    },
  })
  .then(response => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(response));
    setbtnDisable(false);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    alert(err);
    setbtnDisable(false);
  });

axios
  .get("http://smart-trd.ir//service/uservice.aspx?UN=NewSignal&ACT=LastOne", {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": true,
      "Access-Control-Request-Headers": "Content-Type, x-requested-with",
    },
  })
  .then(response => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(response));
    setbtnDisable(false);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    alert(err);
    setbtnDisable(false);
  });

axios
  .get("https://smart-trd.ir/a.json", {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": true,
      "Access-Control-Request-Headers": "Content-Type, x-requested-with",
    },
  })
  .then(response => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(response));
    setbtnDisable(false);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    alert(err);
    setbtnDisable(false);
  });
```

I try 'fetch' instead if 'axios' and I get new error "TypeError: Failed to fetch"

Comment: I've just come across a very similar issue. To "fix" it I removed headers (I only had a  content type header) from the GET call that was causing the Network Error. The network error disappeared. I have another axios call that is identical aside from the URL setup in another thunk and it works fine. I also only see the error on iOS and not Android.

Answer (score 0):

It may be issue with your 2nd and 3rd urls. Your first url is locating to a website but anothers are locating json files. You try with another websites.